How to list All LDAP Groups using PowerShell
I'm Brand new to LDAP Directory related works and seeking your help in fetching all Available LDAP Groups using PowerShell script.
LDAP Server: xxxx.domain.com:636 and have one service account.
Here is full script:
# Define the LDAPS server, port, and credentials
$ldapServer = "my-ldap-server"
$ldapPort = 636 # LDAPS port
$ldapPath = "LDAP://$ldapServer:$ldapPort"
$ldapUser = "your-username"
$ldapPassword = "your-password"

# Create a new DirectoryEntry object with the LDAPS path and credentials
$directoryEntry = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
$directoryEntry.Path = $ldapPath
$directoryEntry.Username = $ldapUser
$directoryEntry.Password = $ldapPassword
$directoryEntry.AuthenticationType = [System.DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes]::SecureSocketsLayer

# Create a new DirectorySearcher object
$directorySearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($directoryEntry)

# Define the filter to search for groups
$directorySearcher.Filter = "(objectClass=group)"

# Define the properties to load (e.g., group name, description)
$directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn")
$directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("description")

# Perform the search
$searchResults = $directorySearcher.FindAll()

# Loop through the results and display group information
foreach ($result in $searchResults) {
    $groupName = $result.Properties["cn"] -join ", "
    $groupDescription = $result.Properties["description"] -join ", "

    Write-Output "Group Name: $groupName"
    Write-Output "Description: $groupDescription"
    Write-Output "-------------------------"
}

# Clean up
$directorySearcher.Dispose()
$directoryEntry.Dispose()


I was able to verify test-connection and found 200 Status for the same. But i was not able to query for LDAP Groups.  Can anyone of you help me in this regard.
Thanks in Advance.
Thanks,
Siva

Is this an Active Directory LDAP server or a non-AD server?

@grawity_u1686 Yes i'm trying from Non-AD server.

In that case, do you have the correct attributes and objectClass name? You seem to be using AD ones, but AD LDAP uses a different schema than 'traditional' LDAP. Have you tried looking at a single group entry using some graphical LDAP browser?

@grawity_u1686 any example please? So that i can verify and confirm you

Apache Directory Studio is a commonly used one. My guess is that you want groupOfNames for the filter but only you can find out for sure.

Currently i've supplied as "objectClass=group"

@grawity_u1686 I just came to know the LDAP Directory will work on On-Prem and not on cloud .hence its failed. Thank you for your insights
